# Self-Service booking flow including payment

Tags: amadeus

I'm checking the self-service API for flight booking. I got the process working ok: Flight Offers Search -> Flight Offers Price -> Flight Create Orders.

I've tried it and I got all the responses OK. I also understand I need to meet a few requirements to do the actual bookings in production.

What I don't understand is:

1) Where do I enter the payment information?

2) If the traveler is paying through credit card, is there an online form that is secure and compliant so I don't actually store the traveler's credit card info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Self-Service the booking works with a consolidator (an entity that will manage the ticketing with the airlines for you). You don't need to pass the payment method in the API call as you will have a contract with the consolidator and have this information directly provided to it. We are about to publish more documentation about it, as of today we open production only to some pilots, if you are interested you can contact us at developers@amadeus.com.
2. This part needs to be managed on your side, you will be the one handling the payment and the secure process to do it.